# ¿Comó coloco orientación horizontal en DomPDF?

Tags: php, html, sql, dompdf

Hola gente estoy generando un reporte en PDF usando la biblioteca DOMPDF, sin embargo, me gustaría usar una orientación horizontal para la hoja, ya que, de manera predeterminada en vertical, adjunto el código, el cual ya funciona sin problemas.

```
<?php ob_start();
$conexion = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'cmbd'); ?>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Consecutivo</th>
            <th>Service Tag</th>
            <th>Usuario</th>
            <th>Diferencia 1</th>
            <th>Diferencia 2</th>
            <th>Falla</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <?php
    error_reporting(0);
    $fechahora = $_POST['fechahora'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM diferencias";
    $result = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);

    while ($mostrar = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $mostrar['consecutivo'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $mostrar['servicetag'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $mostrar['usuario'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $mostrar['dif1'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $mostrar['dif2'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $mostrar['falla'] ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
</table>
<?php
require_once 'dompdf/autoload.inc.php';

use Dompdf\Dompdf;

$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
$dompdf->load_html(ob_get_clean());
$dompdf->render();
$pdf = $dompdf->output();
$filename = "ejemplo.pdf";
file_put_contents($filename, $pdf);
$dompdf->stream($filename);
?>
```

Muchas gracias de antemano, posteriormente agregare estilos CSS para mejorar la estética del reporte, sin embargo, el problema es que quiero manipular la hoja de maneta horizontal

Comment: En la documentación oficial de la librería que estás utilizando debería especificar cómo lograr lo que buscas. Ya lo buscaste?

Comment: https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/blob/master/src/Options.php#L117